# Permission Problems with Déjà Dup

Tags: permissions, backup, deja-dup

When trying to back up my system, I get the following error. I know that there is something going on with permissions but I just do not know exactly what that something is. Will someone please help me? Here is the error:

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. Error: gdata-service-error-quark: 
Authentication required: 
{
 "error": 
  {
  "errors": 
  [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot, I am sure you need to know that I am using Kubuntu 18.04 and my backup folder is located on Google Drive.

Comment: Is that not a google drive authentication issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message explains it pretty well all by itself:

- [Code 401](https://http.cat/401) is HTTP Unautorized
- `Invalid credentials` is a username or password that is incorrect.

Not an Ubuntu Déjà Dup issue, but a Google Authentication issue.

*For further help, please contact Google.*

Comment: And what if credentials are correct but still happens?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu nor GDrive any more @CalinBlaga  :(